# "Predefine" a LaTeX file as master-file using Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, multiple-files

Is there a way to put a command in either the master file or the subfiles in order to sort of predefine the master file? The reason I would like to do this is to avoid having to click on options and define the master file every time I continue working.
I'm not sure if this depends on how I set up my scrartcl - but just in case, here is what the folder with the files and what the master file looks like:

"root" folder: report.tex, mystyle.sty, img folder (images), tex folder (subfiles.tex)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\changefont{ppl}{m}{n}
\input{tex/titlepage}
\newpage
\input{tex/intro}
\input{tex/sec1}
\input{tex/sec2}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{C:/Users/username/bib/clusters}   %%% WINDOWS
%\bibliography{../bib/clusters}   %%% LINUX
\end{document}
```

And the subfiles are really simple, just containing content.

If there is a way to predefine the master file - I suppose that this depends on the editor used. But is there some generell "LaTeX-command" to do this also? So that one can define the master file generally?

Comment: Why no use [`Texstudio`](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/), it's better than `Texmaker` and it allows easily *Set document as master document*?

Comment: I can set the document as the master document easily in Texmaker, too. The question I am asking is whether or not there is a way I can avoid the two clicks necessary for this - by adding a command to the file or something like that.

Comment: You won't need something like this as a LaTeX command. Since LaTeX is basically a program that is run from command line (as well as pdfLaTeX), the user would always choose the 'master document' when s/he uses `latex report.tex`

Comment: As the developers to support magic comments like texshop, texworks, Emacs or arara uses

Comment: No idea about `texmaker` but in `texstudio` it is possible to use such magic comments like `% !TeX root = ../report.tex`. So perhaps `texmaker` might also recognise it.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I was looking for and works with texmaker, too!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have this question officially answered, this was the comment that worked for me:

> No idea about texmaker but in texstudio it is possible to use such magic comments like
>
> % !TeX root = ../report.tex
>
> So perhaps texmaker might also recognise it. – samcarter Feb 20 '16 at 10:50

Answer (score 4):

A workaround in Texmaker is to use *File -> Session -> Save Session* rather than plainly saving the files upon closing the program. It will ask you to define a name and location for the Session-file, called *.tks*.

Make sure you associate the file-type *.tks* with Texmaker in case your OS doesn't recognize it automatically.

Next time you want to work on this project, do so by simply opening the *.tks*-session file (or opening Texmaker and clicking *File -> Session -> Load Session*). This way all the files from your previous session should be open in the editor AND your master document is also already defined as a master document.

In sum: One more click upon closing Texmaker, but way fewer clicks for starting to work on the project.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point: The initiator asked for a "LaTeX-command" and not for a possibility to set this up in an editor like texmaker. However, I think the only way would be doing this in the editor.